# How can I pre-populate the web images search query in Filepicker.io for iOS?

Tags: ios, filepicker.io

I'm using Filepicker.io in a native iOS app. How can I pre-populate the search query for the "Web Images" search field?  For example, I'd like to set the search query to "surfing" if I know the user is looking for a surfing image.

Comment: Heard back from Filepicker and it's not currently possible but they added a feature ticket for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the *openTo* option:

```
filepicker.pick({
        services:['IMAGE_SEARCH'],
        openTo:'/Imagesearch/surfing',
        mimetype:'image/*'
    },
    function(FPFile){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(FPFile));
    },
    function(FPError){
        console.log(FPError.toString());
    }
);
```